# Package 3rd party jar and .so dependency with Maven

Tags: maven, spring-boot

We use a third party jar which is essentially an entrypoint to method definitions provided by two dynamically linked libraries (.so). We want to include these in a maven build. The third party jar is easy, but how do we include the libraries, as without them we're getting a linker error at runtime?

sqlrelay is the third party dependency, which was installed with the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqlrelay.jar -DgroupId=com.firstworks -DartifactId=sqlrelay -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.2.1
```

the runtime error is:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError no SQLRConnection in java.library.path
```

This is a Spring Boot application, here's my pom:

> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>       4.0.0
>
> ```
> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
> <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
> <version>0.1.0</version>
>
> <parent>
>     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
>     <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
> </parent>
>
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
>         <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
>         <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
>         <version>1.11.248</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.firstworks</groupId>
>         <artifactId>sqlrelay</artifactId>             > 
>         <version>1.2.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.bettercloud</groupId>
>         <artifactId>vault-java-driver</artifactId>
>         <version>3.0.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>
> </dependencies>
>
> <properties>
>     <java.version>1.8</java.version>
> </properties>
>
>
> <build>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build>
>
> <repositories>
>     <repository>
>         <id>spring-releases</id>
>         <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
>     </repository>
> </repositories>
> <pluginRepositories>
>     <pluginRepository>
>         <id>spring-releases</id>
>         <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
>     </pluginRepository>
> </pluginRepositories> </project>
> ```

```
mvn clean install
```

builds without error and the application runs. The problem is only hit when an endpoint references the library in question.

Thanks

S

Comment: Platform-specific libraries are other artifacts, that you would have to bundle (in a ZIP for instance) in your "distribution", and reference when launching the JVM, through the `-Djava.library.path`  JVM arg

Comment: Thanks, I've at least got it referencing the so's by explicitly pointing to their path when running the app with -Djava.library.path option. I just need to sort out the pom now.

Comment: It strongly depends on how and where your application is started, but as it seems to be a Spring Boot app packaged as a JAR, all you need is to pull the _.so_ as a dependency (after having pushed it in your local/remote repo) using the maven-dependency-plugin (dependency:copy), then putting the Spring Boot generated WAR and this _.so_ file in the same distribution "thing", such as a ZIP generated with the maven-assembly-plugin